# Angular5 - File is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I have a file.ts file which does not contain a component/service/etc but just a data type.

> When I try to compile my program I get this error: Module build
>   failed: Error: my path\File.ts is missing from the TypeScript
>   compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files'
>   or 'include' property.

Then I changed my tsconfig.app.json file to contain the include tag:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

as the message suggested, but I got this error:

> error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'.
>   Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths
>   were '["**/*.spec.ts"]'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add at least one ts file to your app folder to resolve that error

Comment: I already have some files in the app folder: app.component.ts, app.component.css, app.component.html, app.component.spec.ts,  app.module.ts

Comment: did try include  removing .ts

Comment: Yes, it didn't help.

Comment: "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]

Comment: this is what I did...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169492/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-idov).

Comment: @ldov i have posted my answer and hope it helped to resolve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use correct path and folder name as everything looks fine

Error mentioned in POST is due to path

Other option is to use files

```
"files": [ 
"file.ts"]
```

in tsconfig.json

Check this link for more details- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20091

Comment: the error was due to mismatch in the upper-case/lower-case in the import statement and actual folder name :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had my file name was `logger.ts` however in my spec file I have imported the class with `import { Logger } from '../contracts/Logger';` once I corrected the import with proper case sensitive it worked `import { Logger } from '../contracts/logger';`